# Creating a makefile to compile multiple source file located in different directories

Tags: c, makefile

I'm still learning makefile but I have an issue understanding how to use it properly.

I have a simple project structured as follows:

[image]

I want to use my `Makefile` to compile all source files in sub-directories `Mcal` and `Ecual` without needing to repeat the code for every `.c` file used.

My current code for Makefile is:

```make
#Directories

#Files
FILENAME = blink

#Flags
MCU = atmega16a
WFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wshadow

#Toolchain
COMPILE = avr-gcc -mmcu=$(MCU) -Os $(WFLAGS)
LINK = avr-gcc -mmcu=$(MCU)

# Linking
$(FILENAME): main.o Led.o Dio.o
    $(LINK) $^ -o $(FILENAME)

#Compiling
main.o: main.c
    $(COMPILE) -c $^ -o $@

Led.o: Ecual/Led/Led.c
    $(COMPILE) -c $^ -o $@

Dio.o: Mcal/Dio/Dio.c
    $(COMPILE) -c $^ -o $@
```

I used this but it only works if all source files are located in the root file:

```make
#Compiling
%.o: %.c
    $(COMPILE) -c $^ -o $@
```

Comment: Try using vpath: https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/make_4.html Either the command `vpath %.c Ecual/Led:Mcal/Dio` or the  `VPATH` variable. You'll have to experiment a bit for the exact syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a UNIX-based system, you can use a `shell` directive and the UNIX `find` command to recursively find all .c files in the directory or any subdirectory, then put the result in a variable called `$(SRCS)`. I'm not sure what the equivalent is on Windows machines as I don't have one, but you can find it with Google. The definition would look like this:

```
SRCS := $(shell find . -name "*.c")
```

Then, define `$(OBJS)` to be the same as `$(SRCS)` but replace every `.c` with `.o`. This definition should look like this:

```
OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)
```

Finally, you can then create a rule that depends on `$(OBJS)` and use a generic `%.o: %.c` rule to compile all the C files into object files as you did before. This generic rule will be called whenever a rule depends on a `.o` file and no other rule exists for it. Here would be the final product:

```
#Directories

#Files
FILENAME = blink

#Flags
MCU = atmega16a
WFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wshadow

#Toolchain
COMPILE = avr-gcc -mmcu=$(MCU) -Os $(WFLAGS)
LINK = avr-gcc -mmcu=$(MCU)

SRCS := $(shell find . -name "*.c")
OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)

# Linking
$(FILENAME): $(OBJS)
    $(LINK) $^ -o $(FILENAME)

#Compiling
%.o: %.c
    $(COMPILE) -c $^ -o $@
```

Comment: [Recursive wildcard](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-make/2006-03/msg00091.html) in Gnu Make could be used instead of `find` for non-Unix.

Comment: Windows users can use the same shell commands when running Make e.g. from MSYS2.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my top comments, one way is to use `vpath` and/or `VPATH`

You can get this from `info make`.

I created a simplified version of your `Makefile`:

```
OBJS += led.o dio.o

SPATH := ecual/led mcal/dio
vpath %.c $(SPATH)

FILENAME := blink
all: $(FILENAME)

$(FILENAME): main.o $(OBJS)
    cc $^ -o $@

%.o: %.c
    cc -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f $(FILENAME) *.o
```

---

And, a simplified file hierarchy:

```
.:
total 28
drwxr-xr-x. 3 user user    60 Aug 20 21:22 ecual
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 user user 18400 Aug 20 21:29 final
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user   126 Aug 20 21:31 main.c
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user   204 Aug 20 21:31 Makefile
drwxr-xr-x. 3 user user    60 Aug 20 21:22 mcal

./ecual:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user user 60 Aug 20 21:23 led

./ecual/led:
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user 63 Aug 20 21:23 led.c

./mcal:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user user 60 Aug 20 21:23 dio

./mcal/dio:
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user 63 Aug 20 21:23 dio.c
```

---

Here is the `make` output:

```
cc -c -o main.o main.c
cc -c -o led.o ecual/led/led.c
cc -c -o dio.o mcal/dio/dio.c
cc main.o led.o dio.o -o blink
```